# How to handle relationship with two foreign keys from one table in Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, octobercms, eloquent-relationship

I have table Users and Specialization. :

```
Users:
id (primary, auto increment)
user_id (unique)
hex_id (unique)
status (boolean)

Specialization:
id (primary, auto increment)
user_id (foreign key from users)
hex_id (foreign key from users)
description (text)
```

What should be my controller relationship type between users and specialization? is it one is to one? or or one is to many?

The issue is when I add data to Specialization table during form submit my `user_id` gets auto fill from the relationship but not`hex_id`, giving me the error:

`..hex_id doesn't have default value..`

Is this possible to auto fill both foreign keys in Specialization table using relationship only?

PS I cannot change how the schema was structured.

Comment: What is your hex_id? is it  coming from the authenticated user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we can just add `hax_id` value before record is created, within your `Specialization` model you can add function like below. (make sure remove all validations on `hax_id` field)

> we can use `beforeCreate` event of modal for this. if `user_id` are `hax_id` same then we can just assign it, if in your case it is different then you can fetch user from DB using `user_id` and access its `hax_id` and use it. please check below code.

```php
use \Backend\Models\User;

// inside your `Specialization` model
public function beforeCreate()
{
    $this->hax_id = $this->user_id;
    // or if its not the case and user_id and hax_id are not same then.
    // $user = User::find($this->user_id);
    // $this->hax_id = $user->hax_id;
}
```

> in this way `hax_id` will automatically added to your record. `beforeCreate` will work only on record creation, you can replace `beforeCreate` with `beforeSave` to make this happen all the time create and update.

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: Thank you! I was trying beforeSave() but the `hex_id` is not updated even though I was using `Request::merge()`. `beforeCreate()`  is what I should be using then.

Comment: do not use request etc, just use `$this` as it will have all values assigned to it from request so, anyways good to hear it solved your issue :)

Answer (score 1):

What is your hex_id? is it  coming from the authenticated user?
Also nobody can tell you if it is a one to one or many to may. You should know what you are planning to archive here. 
If a user has many specialization and a specialization belong to a user  then it is a One to Many. Also you don't need user_id and hex_id in user table. The example below is based on your explanation. If you share moere code from your controller we could help you more.

```
In your USERS Model:

public function specializations()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Specialization');
}


In your SPECIALIZATION Model
public function user()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User','user_id');
}`

public function hex()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\User','hex_id');
}`
```